# Update one composite primary key to null in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have an Oracle table created using the following code.

```
create table odetails (
  ono      number(5) not null references orders,
  pno      number(5) not null references parts,
  qty      integer check(qty > 0),
  primary key (ono,pno)
);
```

This is a table given from the source, so I can't make any changes to the table creation. Now I want to update the `pno` to null in some tuples. Since it's a composite key and not null column, I am struggling with writing the constraint and update query.

Comment: Your column is defined as NOT NULL, so you cannot enter a null value. PNO is also part of the primary key, so it may not be nullable. You need to rethink the design.

Comment: @Scott can I alter the table sir?

Comment: Didn't you say "I can't make any changes to the table creation"? That would mean *no, you can't alter the table*.

Comment: @Littlefoot Got your point sir. Thank you